# Testing if a button clicks and makes a paragraph disappear in phantomjs with Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

So at the moment I have a super simple html file where if I click a button, a paragraph disappears. I've tried that and it works. Now I want to test it by running phantomjs as a browser with Selenium webdriver in a testing setup consisting of Mocha and Chai. I can test if the button is there with the correct text, and I can set the CSS of it. I can tell this works from using screenshots for when each test finishes. However, whenever I try to get the button to actually click, the paragraph still remains there in the screenshot.

This is the line I use:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id('hide')).click()
```

But it doesn't seem to work. 
Also when I try to check if the paragraph is there or not, I get a load of errors back.

```
assert.equal(element.getAttribute(), ":hidden", "Paragraph hidden when button clicked");
```

I'm pretty knew to this, so if anybody can show me how or point me to some documentation I would be grateful.

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        console.log("Hiding");
        $("#hide").text("Done somethign")
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Simple Heading to Test</h1>
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and my complete test for hiding the paragraph at the moment

```
 test.it('should hide paragraph', function(){
        driver.get('http://localhost:3000/example.html');
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("/html/body/p")).click()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To test whether or not the paragraph is visible:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('Paragraph') 
if element.is_displayed():
    print "Paragraph found"
else:
    print "Paragraph not found"
```

As for the button, can you post what the errors you are getting are? and can you post the html of the button?

Comment: I've added somemore of the the code. It's not that I'm getting errors, its just the screenshots don't update to show that the button has been clicked.

Comment: Instead of driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("/html/body/p")).click() try driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("hide")).click()